# Obtain number of jobs in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way for the code in the Makefile to know if `gmake` was invoked with the `--jobs=N` option, and obtain the value of `N`?

There is a project which contains a sub-directory with another project, which uses a different build system. That other build system has to be configured. One of the knobs to configure is the number of jobs to use. If nothing is specified, it uses the number of available cpus.

The main Makefile, which runs that other project, already contains `.NOTPARALLEL` and `MAKEFLAGS += -j1`, to make sure only a single job tries to update that sub-directory.

Specifically I want to know if `gmake` was invoked with `-j1`, to build that other project also with the equivalent of `-j1`, to make sure the output on stdout is serialized for easier inspection.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version of GNU Make you have.

In all versions of GNU Make you can check the `MAKEFLAGS` variable for the `-j` option which will tell you if parallel jobs is enabled.

Starting with GNU Make 4.2, the value will also contain the original number of jobs started (so it would be `-j5` or whatever).

I'm not sure what you mean by *to make sure the output on stdout is serialized for easier inspection* but it's not required to disable parallelism to avoid interleaved output, at least if you have GNU Make 4.0 or above: see the `--output-sync` option.

**ETA**

To get out the N in `-jN` the simplest way is this:

```
N := $(patsubst -j%,%,$(filter -j%,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
```

Comment: After poking around it occurred to me that I need to check which variables actually exist. Another post on this site showed the code below the inspect all variables. As you said, there might be the option `-jN` in `MAKEFLAGS` and `MFLAGS` in my version 4.2 of gmake.

So the remaining question is how extract the `N` from `-jN`.


    dump:
        $(foreach v, \
                $(shell echo "$(filter-out .VARIABLES,$(.VARIABLES))" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort), \
                $(info $(shell printf "%-20s" "$(v)")= $(value $(v))) \
        )

    env -i make dump -j1